# Convert list into array dtype=int64 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Can i convert this list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, array([6, 9], dtype=int64), 7, 8, array([6, 9], dtype=int64)]
```

into this:

```
[array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64), array([4], dtype=int64), array([5], dtype=int64), array([6, 9], dtype=int64), array([7], dtype=int64), array([8], dtype=int64), array([6, 9], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, that's an unusual data structure to have.  Given it, though, maybe something like this would work:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.array([6, 9], dtype=np.int64), 7, 8, np.array([6, 9], dtype=np.int64)] 
>>> b = [np.atleast_1d(np.asarray(x,dtype=np.int64)) for x in a]
```

which gives

```
>>> pprint(b)
[array([0], dtype=int64),
 array([1], dtype=int64),
 array([2], dtype=int64),
 array([3], dtype=int64),
 array([4], dtype=int64),
 array([5], dtype=int64),
 array([6, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([7], dtype=int64),
 array([8], dtype=int64),
 array([6, 9], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, array([6, 9], dtype=int64), 7, 8, array([6, 9], dtype=int64)]
new_L = [array(x, dtype=int64) for x in L]
```

Edit:

If you want singleton arrays, then

```
new_new_L = [array(x, dtype=int64) if type(x)==ndarray else array([x], dtype=int64) for x in L]
```

Comment: Nope... new_L = [array(0, dtype=int64), array(1, dtype=int64), array(2, dtype=int64), array(3, dtype=int64), array(4, dtype=int64), array(5, dtype=int64), array([6, 9], dtype=int64), array(7, dtype=int64), array(8, dtype=int64), array([6, 9], dtype=int64)]